# Wagtail: How can I access 'request' in a Page class in models.py

Tags: django, request, wagtail

This is home/models.py:

```py
class HomePage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    template = "home/home_page.html"
    components = {'key1': ['alias1', 'ref1'],
                    'key2': ['alias2', 'ref2'],
                    'key3': ['alias3', 'ref3'],
                    'key4': ['alias4', 'ref4'],
                    'key5': ['alias5', 'ref5']}


    def get_comps(self):
        comps_list = []
        for name in self.components.keys():
           alias = self.components.get(name)[0]

           current_page_url = request.build_absolute_uri

           sub_url_index = current_page_url.find(".")
           ref = "http://" + self.components.get(name)[1] + "." + current_page_url[sub_url_index+1:]
           the_comp = comp(name, alias, ref) 
           comps_list.append(the_comp)
        return comps_list   

class comp(models.Model):
    comp_name = ""
    comp_alias = ""
    comp_ref = ""

    def __init__(self, name, alias, ref):
        self.comp_name = name
        self.comp_alias = alias
        self.comp_ref = ref
```

Wagtail displays an error at the line:

```
current_page_url = request.build_absolute_uri
```

This is because the request object cannot be found which is correct.

How can I access the request object in get_comps()? I do not want to replace this with page.get_full_url or any page methods since that does not give me the absolute URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

```py
   def get_comps(self, request):
        comps_list = []
        for name in self.components.keys():
           alias = self.components.get(name)[0]

           current_page_url = request.build_absolute_uri()

           sub_url_index = current_page_url.find(".")
           ref = "http://" + self.components.get(name)[1] + "." + current_page_url[sub_url_index+1:]
           the_comp = comp(name, alias, ref) 
           comps_list.append(the_comp)
        return comps_list

   def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        comps_list = self.get_comps(request)
        context['comps_list'] = comps_list
        return context
```

In the template (components.html), I have the following:

```html
        {% for comp in comps_list %}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md py-2">{{ comp.comp_name }}</div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{comp.comp_ref}}" target="_blank">{{comp.comp_alias}}</a>
          </div>  
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try placing your logic in the `serve(self, request)` method:  http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/pages.html#more-control-over-page-rendering

Comment: Dan, thanks so much for your suggestion and sharing the link. I visited that link several times yesterday but never paid enough attention. Your suggestion gave me another idea. I did not experiment with `serve(self, request)` , instead, I added it to `get_context(self, request)` since it seemed straightforward. I will post the complete answer here.